Tow column group by in OML4py
How can I group by two columns using OML4Py oml.group_apply invocation?
For instance in sql I can do the following:
'''
select mgr, count(mgr), count(deptno), deptno from emp
group by mgr, deptno
order by deptno;
which returns
7782    1   1   10
7839    1   1   10
0   1   10
7566    2   2   20
7788    1   1   20
7839    1   1   20
7902    1   1   20
7698    5   5   30
7839    1   1   30
'''

Consider the following group_count function:
%python

def group_count(dat):
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.DataFrame([(dat["col1"][0], dat.shape[0])],\
                        columns = ["col1", "COUNT"])

To group by two grouping categories, specify both columns in the index parameter:
index = DF[:,['col2', 'col3']] 

where DF is your oml proxy object and col2 and col3 are your grouping variables.
res = oml.group_apply(oml_iris, index, 
                      func=group_count,
                      oml_input_type="pandas.DataFrame")

